# Remove/Change Facebook like button image

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to remove facebook like button image. My facebook code is bellow..

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=somenumber";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.favoritebd.com" data-send="true"    
data-width="100" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

If i send some message then it's show a image to the left side, I just want to change that Image and where that image come from, i can't find.

Any Idea or Solution...

Answer (score 1):

According to [facebook policy](http://developers.facebook.com/policy/) Item IV. 4. d.

"You must not obscure or cover elements of our social plugins, such as the Like button or Like box plugin."

You can't change the image directly because it's provided by Facebook.